# Choosing a Daw for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu, audio-recording, audio-editing

I currently use Ableton Live 9 and thinking about fully switching to Ubuntu. Ableton has no support nor plans for Ubuntu or Linux, so I have to switch or Wine/VM it. I know using VM/Wine is clunky for midis and sometimes impossible for VM, so I'd rather switch. I looked into a couple daws like LMMS, Bitwig, and Ardour but haven't tried any yet.

I mainly use midi keys, but I also use an Ableton Push and previously used a launchpad which my friend now owns. I love Ableton's ease with midi instruments and ability to use VST plug-ins. My main concern is compatibility with the equipment that I previously stated.

So where should I go from here?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Note we don't provide howtos or the like, neither "general hints" – so please be specific :)

Comment: So no specific requirements for Addons/extensibility, effects, built-in instruments, amps, multi-track, large files, mixing, splitting, exporting to specific formats etc? Consider folks on Linux might have never used Ableton Live (I had to look it up in Wikipedia), but that software you're looking for now, and might not connect the two.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I understood neither abbreviation. Quite some time ago that I've worked with midi last :) Can't hurt to link the terms maybe: isn't it [Virtual Studio Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) and [Digital audio workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation)? Reading it spelled-out I recognized them immediately :) // OK, I'll shut up then. If you're sure it's complete, I'm not pro enough in this area to say otherwise. Consider updating, however, if there are no answers coming ;) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I'm thinking about closing it.
I think Bitwig is pretty much what I am looking for.
I probably should have put this in the music community too.

Comment: Instead of closing it, you could also consider to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if you think you've found what you were looking for ;)

Comment: I can do that? wow xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to use [Bitwig](http://www.bitwig.com/). It has all the capabilities of being able to use all the equipment I listed and runs VSTs very smoothly.

*Bitwig* is available cross-platform (Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux) for currently USD 299 / EUR 299 (there's also a price-reduced "educational version"). A free demo can be downloaded from their website as well.